# Сокращение числа

Tags: java

Есть число например

```
43.300008
```

Но мне нужно чтобы число стало

```
43.3
```

Comment: Что значит "стало"? Вам его нужно вывести с заданной точностью? Вам надо округлить его до заданной точности при вычислениях? Вам надо хранить его с заданной точностью?

Comment: оставить только 43.3 и всё, без округления

Comment: Всё равно непонятно, что значит "оставить". Прочитайте ещё раз первый комментарий и определите, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double num = 43.300008;
    double newDouble = new BigDecimal(num).setScale(1, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue();
    System.out.println("New double: " + newDouble);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно вывести на экран в таком виде, то можно воспользоваться выводом отформатированной строки:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.printf("%.1f%n", 43.300008);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас нет механизмов контроля переменной типа Double, поскольку этот тип предусматривает хранение приблизительного значения дробного числа. Количество хранимых после запятой знаков предопределено размером памяти, выделяемой для этого числа.
Вместе с тем, когда вы говорите о том, что вам нужно, чтобы число "стало" определенной точности , то имеется в виду его визульное представление, то есть вывод в пользовательский интерфейс либо в консоль. Однако, в этом случае фактически вы имеете дело уже не с переменной типа Double, а с переменной типа String, именно для этого существует метод toString(), который вызывается в неявном виде в момент отображения вашего числа, следовательно, нам необходимо выполнять форматирование в момент фактического преобразования Double в String. 
Делается это примерно так:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");
Double d = 43.300008;
String s = formatter.format(d);
System.out.println(s);//43.3
```